# Pandoc and docx (Word for Mac 2011)

Tags: conversion, msword, pandoc, latex-to-word

I'm trying to use Pandoc to convert Markdown with LaTeX math in it ($\alpha$, etc) into Word docx, but every equation I enter comes out broken in the resulting docx file.  I even tried using the [official demo](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demos.html) (#30) for this with the supplied command:

```
pandoc -s math.tex -o example30.docx
```

But the resulting example30.docx still opens with the math broken.

[image: Screenshot of result]

I don't see anything in the issue tracker for Pandoc about this.  Is this a known problem, or is it likely to be something on my end (some boneheaded mistake I'm making, perhaps)?  I'd be grateful for any pointers or suggestions.

Comment: Which pandoc version are you using? I'm getting pretty similar results to the `example30.docx` with `1.9`. Does the `example30.docx` from the pandoc website open properly, just to rule out Word as the culprit?

Comment: Although you are trying to convert a markdown file with some LaTeX markup, I don't think that your problem is about LaTeX at all, which makes your question off-topic in this site. Have you tried the pandoc [mailing lists](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/lists.html)?

Comment: Off topic?  Okay.  I asked it here because it was the TeX that wasn't converting (the Markdown is actually irrelevant to the question).  But for posterity, the problem turned out to be the particular font - Cambria - which, despite this being a clean install of Office, seems to be missing or broken on my system.  Changing the font to XITS Math fixes the math display, so Pandoc is probably off the hook here.